# Auto Height on Container using jQuery Cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I am trying to get the container to automatically calculate the height and am using the following code but with no luck.

The container is called #featured-content

```
/* <![CDATA[ */

var jqu = jQuery.noConflict();

jqu( function () {  

    /* Cycle */
    jqu( '#featured-content' ).cycle( {
        slideExpr: '.featured-post',
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 1000,
        cleartypeNoBg: true,
        pager: '#slide-thumbs',
        containerResize: true,
        slideResize:   false,
        width: '100%',
        timeout: 5000,
        prev: '#slider-prev',
        next: '#slider-next',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function( idx, slide ) { 
            // return selector string for existing anchor 
            return '#slide-thumbs li:eq(' + idx + ') a'; 
        }
    } );
    // call back function to animate the height of the container
    function onAfter(curr, next, opts, fwd) {
        var index = opts.currSlide;
        $('#slider-prev')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
        $('#slider-next')[index == opts.slideCount - 1 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
        //get the height of the current slide
        var $ht = $(this).height();
        //animates the container's height to that of the current slide 
        $(this).parent().animate({ height: $ht });
    }

} );


/* ]]> */
```

Answer (score 0):

Callback function not initiated

```
 after: onAfter,
```

Also try animation "fast"

`$(this).parent().animate({ height: $ht }, "fast");`

Just added code here http://tny.cz/935e48e2